# Can I implement SSO authentication that introduced in VS 2013 with a third party IdP (not Windows Azure AD)?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, azure-active-directory

Microsoft introduced Single Sign-On option for the authentication mechanism in VS 2013. THis works fine with Windows Azure AD.

How can I use the SSO with a third party SAML IdP other than Windows Azure AD?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

It depends on what you mean by the "VS 2013" reference. If you mean "Can I do SAML SSO using VS 2013 and the Change Authentication option?" then the answer is "No" - there is no client side VS 2013 SAML support OOTB.

As per @Wiktor, you can however, use a third party SAML stack, custom STS etc.

You could also do WIF to ADFS and then SAML federation to the SAML IDP.

If you want to do SSO with VS 2013 and the CA option with WIF, then:

Use the "On Premise" option.

Refer: [Use the On-Premises Organizational Authentication Option (ADFS) With ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Note that the article is ADFS centric but as stated:

"allows you to connect to any WS-Federation provider which offers a metadata document. Note that YMMV for any provider other than ADFS, as our testing focused on the latter."

Comment: @Wiktor - apologies - yes you are correct - depends on the interpretation.

Comment: I am too a little bit puzzled by the question but after all this experience with WIF and custom solutions, you would definitely say connecting custom pieces is possible and works if you know what you are doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "and then SAML federation to the SAML IDP." ?

Comment: You federate using SAML metadata exchange - effectively SSO e.g. like http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317734(v=ws.10).aspx